# Mounting a network drive with docker compose on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been successfully mounting volumes on Windows 10 in various projects recently using the example docker-compose.yml file below. For a new project today I needed to mount a folder from the Z:/ drive (a network mounted drive which appears as `\\IP.IP.IP.IP\public\data (Z:)` when I navigate to that area in Windows File Explorer.

When I edit the volumes to point to locations on Z: (e.g. in the second docker-compose.yml below), the volumes are not mounted properly and are empty folders when I connect to the container via the CLI.

Any advice on getting the Z: drive folders to mount properly would be great, thanks.

Working docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - mysql_root
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: donuts
      TZ: "Australia/NSW"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-init.sql
    network_mode: "host"
  
  voyager_donuts:
    container_name: voyager_donuts
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: voyager_donuts
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      TZ: "Australia/NSW"
    volumes:
      - c:/Users/MYUSERNAME/data/DonutsCalibration:/voyager_calibration
      - c:/Users/MYUSERNAME/data/DonutsLog:/voyager_log
      - c:/Users/MYUSERNAME/data:/voyager_data
      - c:/Users/MYUSERNAME/data/DonutsReference:/voyager_reference

volumes:
  mysql-data:

secrets:
  mysql_root:
    file: ./secrets/mysql_root
```

Broken volumes docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - mysql_root
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: donuts
      TZ: "Australia/NSW"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-init.sql
    network_mode: "host"
  
  voyager_donuts:
    container_name: voyager_donuts
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: voyager_donuts
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      TZ: "Australia/NSW"
    volumes:
      - z:/RAW/DonutsCalibration:/voyager_calibration
      - z:/RAW/DonutsLog:/voyager_log
      - z:/RAW:/voyager_data
      - z:/RAW/DonutsReference:/voyager_reference

volumes:
  mysql-data:

secrets:
  mysql_root:
    file: ./secrets/mysql_root
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-map-lan-network-share-to-docker-volume/97276) you would have to use something like this to be able to mount network shares:

```
volumes:
  foldermix:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username={smbuser},password={smbpass},uid={UID for mount},gid={gid for mount},vers=3.0
      device: //Share1/FolderMix
```

See also [the docker documentation for Samba/CIFS volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-cifssamba-volumes).

Of course, if you really need the indirection to mount the network *drive* instead of the network *share*, i.e. because the drive can be mounted to different shares or you do not want to put your credentials into the Docker-Compose file, this will not solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. Adding the samba info etc via driver_opts and pointing to ```//IP.IP.IP.IP/path/to/shared/folder``` for the device got it working. Marked as answer

Comment: @James you awarded the bounty, but it doesn't look like you actually clicked the checkmark ;)